# Heroku and Java - No suitable driver

Tags: java, postgresql, heroku, driver

I know there are lots of answers like this one and I've seen them all and tried what people suggested but nothing worked.
I have this:

```
String dbUrl = System.getenv("JDBC_DATABASE_URL");
connection =  DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl);
```

After printing the value of dbUrl, I have this:

```
jdbc:postgresql://ec2-54-217-213-156.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5432/<DATABASE>
?user=<USER>&password=<PASSWORD>&sslmode=require
```

I don't understand why but I always have the same error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql...
```

I've tried doing in so many ways but I keep getting the same error. Everybody suggested the SSL thing but I have that.

If anybody could help I'd be truly grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my problem. For anybody that might be struggling with the same issue, here's what worked for me.

I forgot to put the maven dependency plugin in my pom, so the mysql driver was not being found.

Just add this to your pom:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals><goal>copy-dependencies</goal></goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have this in your `pom.xml` dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
  <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
  <version>9.4-1201-jdbc4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I solved my problem. I had the dependencies in my pom, it was the maven dependency plugin that I forgot.